# Joining 3 tables to get total target and total sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables in my database like below:

Sman table

```
smanID  |  smanName  | smanTeam    
-------------------------------
0210    | John       | Direct
0211    | Stacy      | Indirect
0212    | Bob        | Indirect
```

SalesTarget table

```
Period    | smanID    |  Target
-------------------------------
201901    | 0210      | 200000
201902    | 0210      | 200000
201901    | 0211      | 200000
201902    | 0211      | 200000
201901    | 0212      | 200000
201902    | 0212      | 200000
```

Sales table

```
Period    | smanID    |  SalesID  | Amount
------------------------------------------
201901    | 0210      |  abc121   | 20000
201901    | 0210      |  abc122   | 80000
201901    | 0211      |  abc123   | 150000
201901    | 0212      |  abc124   | 30000
201902    | 0210      |  abc125   | 35000
201902    | 0211      |  abc126   | 80000
201902    | 0212      |  abc127   | 22000
```

I would like to get the total target, total sales amount and percentage of sales over target generated by each sales team.

I'm running on SQL Server 2012.

This is what I've tried, but I failed to get the correct result except for TotalSales column:

```
SELECT C.smanTeam,
       COALESCE(SUM(A.Target), 0) AS TotalTarget,
       COALESCE(ROUND((SUM(B.[Amount)), 2), 0) AS TotalSales,
       COALESCE(ROUND((((SUM(B.[Amount])) / COALESCE(SUM(A.SalesTarget), '0')) * 100), 0), 0) AS TotalPercentage
FROM Sman_SalesTarget_Current A
     LEFT JOIN [SALESORDER] B ON B.smanID = A.smanID
                             AND B.Period = A.Period
     LEFT JOIN Sman C ON B.smanID = C.SmanID
WHERE B.Period BETWEEN '201901' AND '201902'
GROUP BY C.smanTeam
ORDER BY C.smanTeam;
```

the result that I want should be something like this:

```
salesTeam  | TotalTarget  | TotalSales  | TotalPercentage
---------------------------------------------------------
Direct     | 400000       | 135000      |     33
Indirect   | 800000       | 282000      |     35
```

anyone can probably point out where did I go wrong in my query? I was thinking the join statement but I still cannot fix it.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Hi Larnu, yes, I just shortened it to post my examples here. thanks for the reminder.

Comment: If you look at the natural keys of the tables, do you notice a difference between the sales table and the target table? You should - and there's your hint. You have 2 different levels of aggregation so you can't join directly. For a given period, there is a 1:1 relationship from Sman (nice name btw) to SalesTarget while there is a 1:M relationship between Sman and Sales.

Comment: Hi SMor, thanks! I totally forgot about the 1:M relationship when that is the basics... (just realized the name of Sman table lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This-

```
SELECT A.smanTeam,
A.TotalTarget,
B.TotalSales,
B.TotalSales*100/A.TotalTarget TotalPercentage
FROM
(
    SELECT smanTeam,SUM(Target) TotalTarget
    FROM Sman S
    INNER JOIN SalesTarget ST ON S.smanID  = ST.smanID
    GROUP BY smanTeam
)A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT smanTeam, SUM(Amount) TotalSales
    FROM Sman S
    INNER JOIN Sales SA ON S.smanID  = SA.smanID
    GROUP BY smanTeam
)B ON A.smanTeam = B.smanTeam
```

Comment: thanks! I can just add in the Period parameter if I want to search within two period.

Comment: You are most welcome. You can add any filter as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select smanTeam, sum(Target) TotalTarget, sum(Amount) TotalSales , sum(Target)/sum(Amount) TotalPercentage from (
    select smanTeam, Target, Amount from Sman sm
    join
        (select smanID, sum(Target) Target from SalesTarget group by smanID) st
        on sm.smanID = st.smanID
    join
        (select smanID, sum(Amount) Amount from Sales group by smanID) s
        on sm.smanID = s.smanID
) a group by smanTeam
```